# django python convert unicode in queryset

Tags: python, django

How convert `u'[<Car: { surname :yass name : zazadz } >]` in `[<Car: { surname :yass name : zazadz } >]`.

So how convert unicode in `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` ?

Comment: out of curiosity, how did you get to that point?

Comment: One form of my page contains this : <input type="hidden" name="rP" value="{{ queryCar }}" />.   So I get this value in my view ( request.POST.get("rP","") ) but this value is unicode

Comment: OK, thank you. Must you keep that page as it is or can you change it? If so, what is the purpose of such field? I am trying to understand if there is a better way around this.

Comment: My page contains many querysets but these querysets are not all used ! My page contains 3 links, when I click on link I want pass to page specific to this link one qeueryset

Comment: BTW, the objects in the string/list have no id attribute, so if they refer to existing objects in the DB you would not know which ones they are.

Comment: I'd never hear of anyone trying to post a queryset from a page to the back-end. Normally it's the other way round. And the elements of the queryset are all disjoint, to be displayed/listed on the page

Comment: You can't output a queryset in a form field and pass it back through http post. HTML doesn't know anything about querysets. You'll need to work out some way of passing a simple value which indicates which queryset you want to use.

Comment: Ok thank you.. I will find a solution ;) The problem is I don't want range all queryset in one page and hide/show some querysets depending on click of user...

Comment: initially I asked if you can change the page because it would be easier to pass the predicate that defines the queryset to the page (e.g. `{make='Ford', year='1990'}`) then in the view, parse the posted string into a dictionary you can use to execute a new query.

Comment: I try to don't use the database ^^ so I don't want execution of new query

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I wrote to convert unicode into string which i then process according to my need. 
_in_unicode is the parameter passed to this function, which takes an input of type unicode.

```
def unicode_to_string(_in_unicode):
return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', _in_unicode).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

You will have to write a parser to process that string and then convert it into proper format for data processing.

P.S: If you are downvoting, please add comment for the reason.